# Use default value for report parameter when creating a subscription with ReportingService2010

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am currently trying to set up a web service in C# for users to manage report subscriptions using `ReportingService2010`. I have almost everything working, the issue I am running into is setting a dynamic end date for running the report. The report takes parameters for start and end dates, and want to set the end date to the current day at execution time.

After a bunch of searching online, it seems that I have to set a default in the report, which I set to `=Today()` and I did a test run and it worked fine. However, when I call it through the web service I cannot figure out how to use the default value. I can't pass a null or empty value without it throwing an error.

Is there some way to specify in `ReportingService2010` `CreateSubscription` method to use the report default value for a report parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply apply the "Allow Null Values" to the parameter, in which case the "Default Value" will be used when you omit the parameter from the Parameters collection passed in.